# Fixing Syntax Error in Internet Explorer 11 + Angular 6+ project

Tags: angular6, azure-ad-msal, angular7, msal.js

I'm using the msal.js `"@azure/msal-angular": "^0.1.2"` in both `Angular 6` and `Angular 7` projects and I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
vendor.js (64379,1)
```

The .js code on line 64379

```
class AuthenticationResult {
constructor(token, tokenType) {
    this._token = "";
    this._tokenType = "";
    this._token = token;
    if (tokenType) {
        this._tokenType = tokenType;
    }
}
get token() {
    return this._token;
}
set token(value) {
    this._token = value;
}
get tokenType() {
    return this._tokenType;
}
set tokenType(value) {
    this._tokenType = value;
}}
```

I added `rxjs-compat` npm module to support Angular 6+.

Tried the following fix for IE 11:

`uncommented polyfills.ts`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/Using-msal.js-with-Internet-Explorer

Answer (score 3):

This fix is currently working for me.

**Problem:**
The dist folder(@azure\msal-angular\dist) in NPM package `@azure/msal-angular` is compiled incorrectly for IE11.

**Fix:** 
Recompile the ts files (`https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular`) and add to your projects `node_modules\@azure\msal-angular\dist`

**Steps**

1. clone and npm install https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular
2. npm run `build:modules`
3. copy the newly created files from `lib-es6`
4. paste `lib-es6` files to your angular projects `node_modules\@azure\msal-angular\dist`

`npm start` your angular project.

Answer (score 0):

there is an msal npm package that works basically the same. Im using that in my angular 7 app.

Comment: This is the NPM package that your referencing?  
https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal

Comment: Yeah. Made by same people I think. Haven't really looked into it much as it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known bug, which the developers plan to fix in their **upcoming Version 1.0 of @azure/msal-angular** at about **July-Sep 2019**.

Sources:

- [Github thread concerning that error](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/414)
- [Roadmap where the date stems from](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki#Roadmap)

Answer (score 0):

As per the document of this library. this is only supported in Angular(4.3-5). Didn't support Angular 6 or 7. You need to wait for a release that will support Angular 7.

Ref :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular

> The MSAL library preview for Angular is a wrapper of the core MSAL.js
>   library which enables **Angular(4.3 to 5)** applications to authenticate
>   enterprise users using Microsoft Azure Active Directory (AAD),
>   Microsoft account users (MSA), users using social identity providers
>   like Facebook, Google, LinkedIn etc. and get access to Microsoft Cloud
>   OR Microsoft Graph.